# Close-packing of orthogonal forms

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry

This is a city planning problem.

I'm trying to order some  rectangular buildings of given size within a lot, so that the building corners are always within a max distance D to the other buildings and that there is as little "wasted" space as possible.

Is there a close-packing algorithm I can use for this purpose? Is the Voronai-algorithm in some form applicable?

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: You mean _orthogonal_ forms? right?

Comment: hehe.. yup. sorry... with corners, no circles. Although to simplify maybe an elipse or a circle could be traced around the building envelope. In that case a circle-packing algorithm could be used?

Comment: Are your buildings all rectangular? Or do they have more complex shapes?

Comment: they would probably have more comlex shapes, but to simplify I think it is ok to give them a rectangular shape.

Comment: Related http://dip.sun.ac.za/~vuuren/repositories/levelpaper/spp%5B1%5D.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This requirement

> building corners are always within a
>   max distance D to the other buildings

can be modfied by increasing the outer bounds of each rectangle by an edge of width D/2. This leaves you with a standard 2D Strip packing problem. Here

http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/36005

you find a nice article how to attack those kind of problems, sample programs (C#, VB.NET) included. Here is a Wikipedia article

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

which may help you a little bit, too.

Comment: Thanks, I think the 2D bin packing algorithm in a variation where; a. the shapes can differ, b. the shapes are ordered within an area, not in strips. Now I just have to find some algorithms that can help me achieve this... Would such an alternative have a name? To simplify the search for the algorithm ..? Have a great weekend. Cheers, Eirik

Comment: Or is it so that the number of strips can be deduced from the given shapes divided by the width of the site (area) and therefore it is a strip algorithm afterall?

Comment: @EiriK: I don't know what you mean by "your shapes are ordered within an area". Do you have restrictions for the width of the total area? And can you give a formal definition of what you mean by "as little wasted space as possible?

Comment: Let me try to explain: imagine a camping site and X tents and caravans of different shapes. Now, there is a rule that the tents and caravans should be at least N meters away from each other. There are (at least) two alternatives. Either the tents and caravans are packed close together, with N metres between them. This leaves a large empty space on the camping site if there are not enough guests. The other alternative is that the tents and caravans are spread evenly on the camping grounds, where N is treated as a minimum distance only. I am interested in both.

Comment: the "wasted space" is only relevant for the packed example with the potentially large, unused space. In the evenly spread example this space is also spread between the tents/caravans. I guess I meant that if because of noise or sunlight the tents and caravans are not allowed to be rotated, there might in example 1 also be leftover space between the various shapes, and this should be minimized. Was that clearer, or am I still rambling?

Comment: Well, I think you will have to make some research on your own. But such a problem is simpler to attack if you have a clear goal. Happy weekend, too.